# Remove double quotes from json

Tags: json, groovy

I'm trying to calculate cosine similarity between text and image and I have two json files like this

```
[ {
  "text" : [ -0.1414141058921814, 0.033384405076503754, 0.03852704539895058],
  "id" : "pseudo_label_1"
}]
```

and

```
[ {
  "_img" : "[[-0.0331673,-0.138877,-0.0187086,0.065926]]",
  "key" : "image_1.jpg"
}]
```

How can I remove double quotes and square brackets from a value

```
"_img" : "[[-0.0331673,-0.138877,-0.0187086,0.065926]]"
```

to get the value like this?

```
"_img" : [-0.0331673,-0.138877,-0.0187086,0.065926]
```

Comment: Use substring to get `-0.0331673,-0.138877,-0.0187086,0.065926` out of `[[-0.0331673,-0.138877,-0.0187086,0.065926]]`, then split on comma, then parse every string to a double. Or parse the string `[[-0.0331673,-0.138877,-0.0187086,0.065926]]` as JSON again: you'll get an array containing an arry of numbers at index 0.

Comment: I've made like this  
`def results = []  
def res = _._img[2..-3].split(',')  
for(item in res){  
  results.add(item.toFloat())}  
results`

Comment: Don't put them there in the first place.  this looks alot like something did a `.toString()` before it got stored as JSON.